# Taps gem is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

I'm currently importing from Heroku a postgree database to my machine using Taps.

The database is around 5MB and has around 20k objects.

It is taking like 15 minutes so far.

Any idea why is taking so long and is there any way to make this faster? I can't imagine to work this way when the database grow 1 million objects and I need to do some moving on a harry.

```
messages:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:11:07
```

(that was a table with only 14k objects )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading a backup is likely to be a lot quicker, if you have the (free) pgbackups addon and you don't mind the extra step of restoring the dump.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Comment: I begin with that, and I couldn't import the dump into local db. That's why I choose to use Taps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852631/how-to-import-a-heroku-pg-dump-into-local-machine#comment14135966_10852631

Comment: Ah sorry to send you round in circles. I'm no postgresql expert but did you try pg_restore rather than psql? e.g. `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h myhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump`. Based on the errors you were getting earlier it looks like psql doesn't handle backups in the format that heroku uses.