# Rails import database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to import a database from my computer to heroku but it keep on saying unknown command for that.Even I am confuse about it which command to use .I have a postgre sql database.I want to know how to import a database

```
   push from SOURCE_DATABASE to REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE
 REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE must be empty.

 SOURCE_DATABASE must be either the name of a database
 existing on your localhost or the fully qualified URL of
 a remote databas
```

So what will be the remote_target_database ??? 
and do i need to specify my full path to source database ?

Comment: The error message is helpful. You want `heroku pg:push` not db:push

Comment: It obviously says: `Perhaps you meant "pg:push"`. Did you try that instead?

Comment: how will i specify database name?

Comment: and path of my database?

Comment: Add that to the question body instead of writing it in the comments please.

Comment: OK i am updating my question

Comment: This link might help you: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push

Comment: that article I have already seen that but was having some doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.

heroku pg:push your_app_name_development DATABASE_URL

Comment: heroku pg:push my_Database_name it is showing me error

Comment: This worked for me! by `your_app_name_development` did you mean something more like `development_database_name`?

Answer (score 0):

PG Backups can be used as a convenient tool to import database dumps from other sources into your Heroku Postgres database.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export
- [How to import a Heroku PG dump into local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852631/how-to-import-a-heroku-pg-dump-into-local-machine)