# heroku pg:pull pg_dump: command not found

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Been trying to pull my remote db into local env with heroku pg:pull, prior without problems, but at this point the command is returning this:

```
/bin/sh: pg_dump: command not found
 ▸    pg_dump errored with 127
pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
```

looked for an answer here and updated the bash profile as some topics mention:

export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin:$PATH

rebooted and restarted terminal, but with no avail. anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I think you will find your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391586/6392696

Comment: Can confirm also having this issue. Making a manual backup, downloading from the Durability tab, and running pg_restore manually per @nourza's link seems to be working

Comment: I will put it in new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ypsql tries to interpret SQL queries while you are adding it a compressed dump (heroku use this).

When You can not read the dump, pg_restore -O latest.dump gives you valid SQL you may pipe to psql

the easiest here :

```
pg_restore -O -d app_development latest.dump
```

Imporatant:

Try Use -O  you may not use the random username of your remote heroku postgres db.

Check this link for more help here stackoverflow.com/a/11391586/6392696

Comment: thanks nourza this worked. will try later if I can still use the heroku pg:pull command line since it is so convenient

Answer (score 0):

Update your Heroku CLI; the issue where Postgres.app paths weren't being handled correctly was just fixed. https://github.com/heroku/cli/pull/1074