# ERROR: syntax error at or near "PGDMP" LINE 1: PGDMP

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, phppgadmin

I am trying to upload a postgres database backup file to my hosting server. But I am getting these errors. No idea what is wrong with this file.[image]

Comment: Please describe what exactly you did to get that error.

Comment: I created a backup file which is a .sql file. And then I executed that file inside phppgadmin  on my hosting server.

Comment: i think you can get idea from this  [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391586/8928037)

Answer (score 5):

I got my the answer. Just backup in plain format rather than custom. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a .sql file when uploading the database to your new stack. By default, Heroku gives you a .dump file. What worked for me was copying the database to my local development pg db using the .dump file and then using that to generate a .sql file which I pushed to my new app.

or

adapted to support the latest official dokku postgres plugin, `pg_restore -O latest.dump | dokku postgres:connect <db_name>`

Comment: But the backup is a .sql file. That is what I am using.

Comment: `pg_restore -O latest.dump | dokku postgres:connect <db_name>` can you use this command to postgres plugin?

Comment: I am new to postgres using it on browser. This command for dokku did not work for me.